# can i test once using real admob ads before publishing?

Tags: ios, admob, ads

I am done developing version one of my iOS app that uses admob ads. I haven't published it to the App Store yet, and I was wondering if I could replace the test ads with real ads and run it on my device only once to make sure the real ads work? Or do I have to just switch the test ad ids with my real ad ids and submit it to the App Store and hope for the best?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change AD ids to the production ones, upload the build on TestFlight. Once you download the build from TestFlight on your device you should be able to see Ads. Make sure your everything fine and then submit the build to AppStore for review.

Comment: Is it possible to display multiple Ads in each recurring items?